# Trouble using variables from my custom adapter

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley, custom-adapter

I am using a list view and creating a custom adapter. I am trying to like a post every time the button is clicked. The button being declared is connected with each item in the list view. There are three problems that I am encountering:

1) When I click on the like button, a "random" button down the list is also clicked.

2) When I click like, it updates the like count, but when I scroll down out of view, then scroll back up, the like count is reset.

3) When I click like, the like count will change, now when I click like on a different post, the like count changes to whatever the like count was on the first like button I clicked.

I have been stuck on this for a while any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for adapter class:

```
    class PostsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Posts> implements View.OnClickListener {
    //used to create views from xml
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public PostsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Posts> posts) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, posts);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    //add to xml from dataset
    @Override
    // view convertview = recycled view
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;
        Posts posts = getItem(position);

        //checks if recycled view is null, thewn creates new view, if not null, use same view
        if(view == null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_posts, null);

            Button like = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);
            TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            TextView user = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
            TextView topic = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topic);
            TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            TextView likes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
            TextView hiddenId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenID);

            holder = new Holder(content, user, topic, date, likes, hiddenId, like);

            view.setTag(holder);
            like.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.content.setText(posts.getContent());
        holder.user.setText(posts.getUser());
        holder.topic.setText(posts.getTopic());
        holder.date.setText(posts.getDate());
        holder.likes.setText(posts.getLikes());
        holder.hiddenId.setText(posts.getId());

        holder.like.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button like = (Button) v;
        Holder holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(DisplayPosts.this, "Button: " + like.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        createLike(holder.like, holder.hiddenId, holder.likes);
    }
}

static class Holder{
    public TextView content;
    public TextView user;
    public TextView topic;
    public TextView date;
    public TextView likes;
    public TextView hiddenId;
    public Button like;

    public Holder(TextView content, TextView user, TextView topic, TextView date, TextView likes, TextView hiddenId, Button like) {
        this.content = content;
        this.user = user;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.date = date;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.hiddenId = hiddenId;
        this.like = like;
    }
}
```

Here is createLike method:

```
    private void createLike(final Button like, final TextView hiddenid, final TextView likes){
    final String hid = hiddenid.getText().toString().trim();

    if(like.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("like")){
        like.setText("UnLike");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "LikePost.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        try {
                            //json string to jsonobject
                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            //get json sstring created in php and store to JSON Array
                            result2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.json_array_likes);
                            //get username from json array
                            likes.setText(getLikeCount(result2));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                // corresponding values.
                Map<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                //maps specified string key, to specified string value
                hashMap.put(Config.hid, hid);
                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        //add string request to queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    else{
        like.setText("Like");
    }
}
private String getLikeCount(JSONArray jsonArray){
    String lc = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            likeCount.add(json.getString(Config.getLike));
            lc = likeCount.get(0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
    return lc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root issue is that you are using a static modifier on your holder class, drop this and I believe it will solve your issue.

Comment: Did not fix the problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Try this -

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createLike(position,holder.like, holder.hiddenId, holder.likes);//Added one more parameter "position"
             }
);
```

Now in `createLike()` you have to update your dataset "`posts`" with the new like count in for the item at "`position`" -

```
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                            try {
                                //json string to jsonobject
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                //get json sstring created in php and store to JSON Array
                                result2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.json_array_likes);
                                //get username from json array
                                likes.setText(getLikeCount(result2));

//Update like count here
posts.get(position).setLikeCount(); //The count which you want to update

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I made some of your changes and posted below. @Shadab Ansari

Comment: Use getItem(position) instead of posts.

Comment: getSelectedItem? getSelectedItemPosition? getItem did not resolve. @Shadab Ansari

Comment: Posts posts = getItem(position); This is the way you are using in getView(). This should work in your adapter too.

Comment: Thank you for helping but I don't quite understand what I am supposed to do. I think I may be misunderstanding you. I have this   
Posts posts = getItem(position); already in the adapter class. I can't get that variable 'posts' in createLik method. @Shadab Ansari

Comment: Calculate again where you need it .

Comment: Can you explain to me in more detail what this means please? :: Now in createLike() you have to update your dataset "posts" with the new like count in for the item at "position"...

Comment: Try  getItem(position).setLikeCount();

Comment: It is not letting me use the getItem method

Comment: private List<Posts> mPosts; public PostsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Posts> posts) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, posts);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); this.mPosts = posts;
    }  And use mPosts.get(position); instead of getItem(position);

Comment: I did as you said. Now what's the next step? I am still unable to use mPosts.get(Position) inside the createLike method.

Comment: Where is your createLike() method - inside the adapter or outside it or inside the Holder class?

Comment: it is outside the adapter

Comment: That's the reason . If that's outside the adapter then how do you think you will be able to access the private members of the adapter. You should have that method in the adapter only. Change your design according to that.

Comment: Okay I have made the adjustment. I am still getting the problem where a "random" button text is changed to 'unlike' down the list when 'like' is clicked. It doesnt affect the like count though just the text. Also, when I scroll out of view the like count is reset in the view. I posted updated code.

Comment: You need to update your `mPosts` also at the same time when you update the like/unlike text using  `mPosts.get(position).setLikes();` with the updated count.

Comment: Hm how can I get the updated count there, since the response doesnt come until later.

Comment: you are doing `likes.setText(likenum);` in onResponse() .Update mPosts also there.

Comment: Awesome! Problems 2 and 3 are fixed. Now it's just problem 1. Another button down the list is also being clicked.

Comment: Is there a reason why if I click one button, its also triggering the text of another button down the list? Do I have to change something here? : private void createLike(final int position, final Button like, final TextView hiddenid, final TextView likes){
            final String hid = hiddenid.getText().toString().trim();
            mPosts.get(position);
            if(like.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("like")){

                like.setText("UnLike");
              ...

Comment: I am still stuck on  this problem. Any more help would be appreciated. @Shadab Ansari

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
    public class PostsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Posts>  {
    //used to create views from xml
    Context context;
    int textViewResourceId;
    ArrayList<Posts> mPosts = new ArrayList<Posts>();

    public PostsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Posts> posts) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, posts);
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.mPosts = posts;
    }

    // view convertview = recycled view
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final Holder holder;
        //checks if recycled view is null, thewn creates new view, if not null, use same view
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);

            Button like = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);
            TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            TextView user = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
            TextView topic = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topic);
            TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            TextView likes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
            TextView hiddenId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenID);
            holder = new Holder(content, user, topic, date, likes, hiddenId, like);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        Posts posts = mPosts.get(position);
        holder.content.setText(posts.getContent());
        holder.user.setText(posts.getUser());
        holder.topic.setText(posts.getTopic());
        holder.date.setText(posts.getDate());
        holder.likes.setText(posts.getLikes());
        holder.hiddenId.setText(posts.getId());

        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createLike(position, holder.like, holder.hiddenId, holder.likes);//Added one more parameter "position"
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void createLike(final int position, final Button like, final TextView hiddenid, final TextView likes){
        final String hid = hiddenid.getText().toString().trim();

        if(like.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("like")){
            like.setText("UnLike");
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "LikePost.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                            try {
                                //counter
                                n+=1;

                                //json string to jsonobject
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                //get json sstring created in php and store to JSON Array
                                result2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.json_array_likes);
                                //get username from json array
                                String likestring = getLikeCount(result2);
                                String likenum = mPosts.get(position).getLikes(likestring);
                                likes.setText(likenum);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    // corresponding values.
                    Map<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    //maps specified string key, to specified string value
                    hashMap.put(Config.hid, hid);
                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            //add string request to queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DisplayPosts.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
        else{
            like.setText("Like");
        }
    }
    private String getLikeCount(JSONArray jsonArray){
        System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonArray);
        String lc = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                likeCount.add(json.getString(Config.getLike));
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
                lc = likeCount.get(n - 1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("LC: " + lc);
        return lc;
    }
     class Holder{
        public TextView content;
        public TextView user;
        public TextView topic;
        public TextView date;
        public TextView likes;
        public TextView hiddenId;
        public Button like;

        public Holder(TextView content, TextView user, TextView topic, TextView date, TextView likes, TextView hiddenId, Button like) {
            this.content = content;
            this.user = user;
            this.topic = topic;
            this.date = date;
            this.likes = likes;
            this.hiddenId = hiddenId;
            this.like = like;
        }
    }
}
```